# Parse.com: Default parameters to identify user?

Tags: javascript, api, parse-platform, parameters, parse-cloud-code

When calling one of my own Cloud Code functions, is there a parameter added by default, that represents the calling user or do I just have to add that myself? I wasn't able to find anything on this in the [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#cloud-code).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logged in user who made the request to your cloud code is in `request.user`, assuming that you're using one of the supplied SDKs or that you set the appropriate details when you use the RESTful interface.

Comment: Well, that was easy. Thanks a lot!